# How i operation on Back Button in fragment. ask for back button of hardware of phone

Tags: android, tabs, fragment, swipe, android-fragmentactivity

i want to operation on back button in main fragment class. i am use swipe tab with help of fragment. so in as par activity class i know function of back button. but this is not help of me. this is my code. i already done on action bar home function. so i want to do same as back button

```
               public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Metals","Forex" };
 static int i = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    i=0;
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

                viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
           //       actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        Log.d("back", "backkk");
        i = 1;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back"+i,100).show();
        onBackPressed();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: you just have to override the back button and then you can add whatever you want ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you want to perform an opration when back key is pressed in Fragment

So Create a public method in fragment

and from Fragment activity class , override onBackkeypressed call that method

example

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.listfragment);
     fragment.doSomthing()

}
```

Comment: Can u  explain me in detail. i did not know any thing in fragment. so please tell me how to override that.

Comment: are you created a Fragment class?@user3725606

Comment: yes.. i post my whole class. i am create swipe tab view

Comment: in FragmentActivity class you can override onBackPressed()

Comment: but how i dont know. if you know then please help me. give me any ex. or give any file which you create

Comment: just paste my code(remove code in {} tags) in your class MainActivity.

Comment: yes thank you its done. its so much simple. but i was not got thats why i make me trouble. thankx....

Comment: may be i cant. stackoverflow not permit to put my answer dnt know why